# How to programatically add multiple sorts using Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, sql-order-by

I have the following code:

```
public IOrderedQueryable<TEntity> Query<TEntity>(Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> filter,
    params Tuple<Expression<Func<TEntity, object>>, bool>[] orderBy)
{
    IQueryable<TEntity> query = DbContext.Set<TEntity>();
    if (filter != null)
    {
        query = query.Where(filter);
    }
    if (orderBy != null)
    {
        query = orderBy.Aggregate(query, (current, tuple) => 
        current.OrderBy(tuple.Item1, tuple.Item2));
    }

    return query;
}
```

And the OrderBy method:

```
public static IQueryable<T> OrderBy<T>(this IQueryable<T> source, Expression<Func<T, object>> keySelector, bool ascending)
{
    var selectorBody = keySelector.Body;
    // Strip the Convert expression
    if (selectorBody.NodeType == ExpressionType.Convert)
        selectorBody = ((UnaryExpression)selectorBody).Operand;
    // Create dynamic lambda expression
    var selector = Expression.Lambda(selectorBody, keySelector.Parameters);
    // Generate the corresponding Queryable method call
    var queryBody = Expression.Call(typeof(Queryable),
        ascending ? "OrderBy" : "OrderByDescending",
        new Type[] { typeof(T), selectorBody.Type },
        source.Expression, Expression.Quote(selector));
    return source.Provider.CreateQuery<T>(queryBody);
}
```

but when I want I invoke the `Query` method, it always applies only the last sort from parametter `orderby`. For example for below call

```
var rows = service.Query<Product>(x=>x.Active, new Tuple<Expression<Func<Product, object>>, bool>(x=>x.Category, true), new Tuple<Expression<Func<Product, object>>, bool>(x=>x.Name, true))
```

The object rows is sorted only by `Name` property. I want to be sorted by `Category` property then by `Name` property.

Is there a way to solve this issue?

**EDITED**

I solved the problem by adding a second extension

```
public static IOrderedQueryable<T> ThenBy<T>(this IOrderedQueryable<T> source, Expression<Func<T, object>> keySelector, bool ascending)
{
    var selectorBody = keySelector.Body;
    // Strip the Convert expression
    if (selectorBody.NodeType == ExpressionType.Convert)
        selectorBody = ((UnaryExpression)selectorBody).Operand;
     // Create dynamic lambda expression
    var selector = Expression.Lambda(selectorBody, keySelector.Parameters);
    // Generate the corresponding Queryable method call
    var queryBody = Expression.Call(typeof(Queryable),
    ascending ? "ThenBy" : "ThenByDescending",
    new Type[] { typeof(T), selectorBody.Type },
    source.Expression, Expression.Quote(selector));
    return (IOrderedQueryable<T>)source.Provider.CreateQuery<T>(queryBody);
}
```

Comment: For nested sorting you need to use [```ThenBy```](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.queryable.thenby(v=vs.110).aspx) method

Comment: How can I write an extension for ThenBy?

Comment: On same manned how it done for ```OrderBy```. You need only remember, that if you have several conditions to sort, forst condition should be called with ```OrderBy```, others with ```ThenBy```, like ```products.OrderBy(x=>x.Name).ThenBy(x=>x.Price)```

Comment: Don't put a "Solved" section in to your question, if you solved your own problem delete that part from your question and post it as an answer in the answer section and mark it accepted after 2 days.

Comment: When I did like you said, other guy said to put the solution in the question.